# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Grid' of undefined thrown in Table.forceUpdateGrid

Tags: react-virtualized

I am attempting to call `tableInstance.forceUpdateGrid()` inside a `Promise.then()` callback and it is throwing an exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Grid' of undefined`

Looking at the following code

```
_createClass(Table, [{
  key: 'forceUpdateGrid',
  value: function forceUpdateGrid() {
    this.Grid.forceUpdate();
  }
```

the `this` reference is undefined...

the only thing I can think of is that in-between the initial BE api call and the `Promise.then()` handler, there has been a props change that has caused the containing component to re-render and maybe the `tableInstance` reference no longer points to the correct instance?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use `fat arrow functions` to get `this` reference inside function :-

```
_createClass(Table, [{
  key: 'forceUpdateGrid',
  value: forceUpdateGrid = () => {
    this.Grid.forceUpdate();
}
```

(2)Or,

```
 let thisRef = this; 
_createClass(Table, [{
  key: 'forceUpdateGrid',
  value: function forceUpdateGrid() {
    thisRef.Grid.forceUpdate();
  }
```

i hope it helps!